# GCC How to export a function from static library

Tags: c++, macos, linker, shared-libraries, symbols

I want to create a shared library from several static libs using GCC under OS X.

In some static libs, there's no code in shared library call it, I just want to export the symbols in these static libs. This works under debug mode, but doesn't under release mode (especially when I enable the dead code striping). I can understand the reason, gcc think these functions on static libs are never used. but how can I force gcc to include these symbols?

I already tried adding -u option for loader, but it only generates a 'local' symbol. how to make linker generate an export symbol?

Also, I'm wondering if there's a way to add the linker directives in source code, just like the MSVC `#pragrma comment(linker, "/INCLUDE:xxxx")`

the function I defined in static lib is like:

```
extern "C"
void test() {}
```

Thanks in advance!
-Jonny

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `--whole-archive`?

Answer (score 0):

Use ar to disassemble the static libraries into their constituent object files. Then link those objects together to make the shared library.

```
ar -x libstatic.a
(produces a bunch of *.o files)
gcc -shared -olibshared.so *.o # Linux
ld -dylib -olibshared.dylib *.o # Mac OSX
```